# Changing the username on Stack Exchange Islam

Tags: discussion

I want to know if I can or if there is a way to change the username on Stack Exchange Islam? Because I have created an account and I forgot to put my username on it and a picture. And if there is a way to change a username tell me.

Comment: Go on profile settings on the full site and it should come up with options to edit your username and picture

Comment: Can you be more clear,please?I mean to show steps

Comment: Thanx for the answer

Answer (score 2):

As @Armaan mentioned briefly, you ought to go on profile setting. For further details, read the following:

At the first step, you should go to your profile setting; actually, you can go to your profile which is available at the top part of your page. Then click on that, later on, go to "Edit Profile & Setting" which is available almost on the top part of the page, on the left).

Eventually you can change/edit your username by editing the part which is shown "Display name"!